# Converting to correct data format

Tags: pandas, time, format

I need your help guys

I have information with wrong time format.

**For example**:

> it shows 1245 or 1837 etc. I want them to be like in correct format:
>   12:45 PM or 6:37 PM.

How can I convert it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need convert [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) or [`dt.time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.time.html):

See also http://strftime.org/.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[1245, 1837]})
print (df)
   date
0  1245
1  1837

print (pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%H%M'))
0   1900-01-01 12:45:00
1   1900-01-01 18:37:00
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

#for string output
print (pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%H%M').dt.strftime('%I:%M %p'))
0    12:45 PM
1    06:37 PM
Name: date, dtype: object

#for time output
print (pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%H%M').dt.time)
0    12:45:00
1    18:37:00
Name: date, dtype: object
```